# Saving HTML content of any URL in a text file in Java

Tags: java, url

I am trying to Save HTML Content of any URL  as Text file in java but its not work How save it?
My code is

```
import java.io.*;

class DemoTest {
    public static void main(String st[]) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\new.html");
            //a.html or pass tha path of html
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("b.txt");//to writw source in file
            while (true) {
                int i = fis.read();
                if (i == -1)
                    break;
                System.out.print((char) i);//display on cmd
                fos.write(i);// write the source in b.txt

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not swallow exceptions. `catch (Exception e) { }`.

Comment: Err, what you are doing here is copying one file to another...

Comment: If you change the path to eg c:\temp\new.html (and you must have this file present) then does it work?  Anyway the answer is in the exception which you hide.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Files.copy()`:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(sourceFile), Paths.get(dstFile));
```

If you have a `URL` object, you can copy its stream directly:

```
Files.copy(url.openStream(), Paths.get(dstFile));
```

[Javadoc for `Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("fileName.txt");
//for each line in the HTML content, read it in as a string variable
writer.println(lineStringVariable);
writer.close();
```